# Removing a certain region from a pbf file

Tags: openstreetmap

I have a PBF file from the complete planet and I want to insert that data into a PostGIS database. However, I would like to exclude a certain region, e.g. all data that belongs to the islands of Japan.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [osmium-extract](https://docs.osmcode.org/osmium/latest/osmium-extract.html) command from the "osmium tool" suite.

One of the example config files in (https://github.com/osmcode/osmium-tool/blob/master/extract-example-config/extracts.json) already include two examples on how to exclude a certain region from a larger area:

- "Brandenburg area without Berlin specified using a poly file with hole", along with the respective poly file: https://github.com/osmcode/osmium-tool/blob/master/extract-example-config/brandenburg.poly
- "City of Cologne suburbs without city center specified using an inline multipolygon description"

If your case, you would need to define an outer polygon ring covering the whole globe, then an inner ring with the areas you want to exclude.